# Carousel won't paginate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, carousel, vue-component

I'm attempting to iterate over the results of an API call (which returns an array of a 100 items) in a vue-carousel. While the data is displayed, I lose the ability to paginate the information. I'm missing the dots at the bottom of the section. The manual mock setup works as expected, i.e. I manually setup a slide. Reviewing the info in the console, I see that I have lost the pagination section that is defined in the other working mock components. Below is the code that I have.

```
        <div  v-for="place in sightsJSONData" :key="place.id">
            <slide class = "slide_view " >
               <span> <h6>{{place.name}}</h6></span>
            </slide>
        </div>
```

import { Carousel, Slide } from "vue-carousel";
components: {
    Carousel,
    Slide
  }

Thank you in advance for all your help

Comment: `carousel ` wrapper missing over slide, try to move the `v-for` in `slide` and replace the `div` with `carousel`